# Дублирование в БД. Как победить?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql-server, проектирование

[image: Получившаяся схема данных]

Напало дублирование, видимо из-за неверного проектирования.

Комментарии к схеме:
- к заказу (Order) привязываются услуги (Service) с помощью таблицы (Order_Service)
- каждая услуга заказа (Order_Service) выполнена сотрудником, связь: таблица (Employee_Order_Service)
- услуги представлены двух видов:
    + перевод (TranslationInfo), хранит имя текста, который переводят, языки с которого и на который переводят (LangFrom, LangTo)
    + заверение перевода (NotarialInfo), хранит, также имя текста, языки, кол-во копий заверения.

---

Но тут такой изъянище...
Такая проблема, посмотрите, вид услуги "перевод" и "заверение" содержат *много одинаковых полей*, а именно: имя файла, язык 'с', язык 'на'. Поэтому при изменении, к примеру, имени текста - нужно будет менять его и в TranslationInfo и в NotarialInfo. *Заверять можно только те тексты, которые переводились*, так что лучше было бы разместить поле "CopyCount" в таблице "TranslationInfo", а таблицу "Notarial" не создавать вовсе! 
Но у заверения должен быть свой исполнитель, своя цена. У перевода тоже, соответственно, свой исполнитель и цена.
Как быть? Как исправить?

Comment: а почему бы вам не объединить таблицы TranslationInfo и NotarialInfo в одну с колонкой typeId

Comment: При таком подходе стоит ли выносить "различающиеся поля" в отдельные таблицы и связывать их внешним ключом с получившейся общей? Или оставить поля и той и той услуги вместе, и выбирать нужные исходя из typeId?
Напишите в ответах это, я поставлю Вам решение, спасибо!

Comment: Я поспешил, typeId будет содержать значения типа - (перевод, перевод_и_заверение)? Но для заверения и для перевода должна быть возможность указывать исполнителей, отдельно для заверения и отдельно для перевода, так же у этих услуг разные цены, не может быть цены за перевод+заверение.

Comment: и в чём проблема? у вас цены в отдельной таблицы Service. Вам надо просто в табличку Order_Service добавить поле ServiceInfoID (это PK из общей таблицы TranslationInfo и NotarialInfo) и всё тогда у вас встанет на место, остальное трогать вообще не придётся

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, Вам помогут внешние ключи с каскадными ограничениями (constraint foreign key) - можно будет менять значение в одной "главной" таблице, значения в остальных "зависимых" таблицах изменятся автоматически. Архитектуру же можно будет оставить текущую.

Comment: AntonioK, одна из таблиц "TranslationInfo", "NotarialInfo" назначается главной, в зависимой таблице повторяющиеся поля отмечаются этими ключами, и будут меняться, если эти поля будут изменятся в главной таблице, я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Да, например так. Не призываю Вас сразу браться за реализацию - полистайте маны, изучите возможности ограничений внешних ключей. Это только один из возможных инструментов.

Comment: Спасибо. Это метод, скорее для исправления уже существующего, мне бы хотелось изменить структуру, чтобы не пришлось потом пользоваться такими способами.

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизировать нужно те места, которые реально создают проблемы. Во многих случаях разработчики *сознательно* допускают некоторую избыточность данных. Критерий может быть такой: если избыточность помогает упростить наиболее частые операции, пусть она будет!
"Лишние" таблицы наверняка усложнят запросы, а "лишние" поля скорее упростят.

Я не знаю вашей предметной области, на мой сторонний взгляд:

1. В таблице выполненных услуг было бы логично разместить прямую ссылку на исполнителя. Промежуточная таблица Employee_Order_Service здесь лишняя.
2. Так ли необходимо держать отдельные таблицы для переводов и для заверений? Может быть достаточно иметь одну таблицу с указанием типа услуги (ссылка на Service) и полным набором полей, необходимым для *всех* услуг. Пускай некоторые из них в некоторых случаях не используются.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал вот такую простенькую схему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ордере могут быть несколько текстов, каждый текст может переводится на несколько языков. Каждая работа выполняется отдельным сотрудником. Схема конечно банальная и не учитывает всю Вашу специфику...